# Fix menu position for WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I'm using **Astra** theme with **Elementor** to build on website using WordPress.

I have gone through these websites: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/sticky-menu-wordpress and https://themeskills.com/find-css-class-id-wordpress/

And, in my Customising -> Additional CSS , I have written below code:

```
#masthead {
height:60px;
z-index:100;
margin:0 auto;
 border-bottom:0.5px solid #dadada;
 width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
text-align: center;
```

}

However, I'm unable to stick the menu. Image here:

[image]

```html
<header class="site-header ast-primary-submenu-animation-fade header-main-layout-1 ast-primary-menu-enabled ast-hide-custom-menu-mobile ast-menu-toggle-icon ast-mobile-header-inline" id="masthead" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPHeader" itemscope="itemscope" itemid="#masthead">

            
            
<div class="main-header-bar-wrap">
    <div class="main-header-bar">
                <div class="ast-container">

            <div class="ast-flex main-header-container">
                
        <div class="site-branding">
            <div class="ast-site-identity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization" itemscope="itemscope">
                            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- .site-branding -->
                <div class="ast-mobile-menu-buttons">

            
                    <div class="ast-button-wrap">
            <button type="button" class="menu-toggle main-header-menu-toggle ast-mobile-menu-buttons-fill" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false" data-index="0">
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Main Menu</span>
                <span class="menu-toggle-icon"></span>
                            </button>
        </div>
            
            
        </div>
            <div class="ast-main-header-bar-alignment"><div class="main-header-bar-navigation"><nav class="ast-flex-grow-1 navigation-accessibility" id="site-navigation" aria-label="Site Navigation" itemtype="https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" itemscope="itemscope"><div class="main-navigation"><ul id="primary-menu" class="main-header-menu ast-nav-menu ast-flex ast-justify-content-flex-end  submenu-with-border astra-menu-animation-fade " aria-expanded="false"><li id="menu-item-1510" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-17 current_page_item menu-item-1510"><a href="http://this-is-for-so.com/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1508" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1508"><a href="http://this-is-for-so.com/all-courses/">Cloud</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1509" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1509"><a href="http://this-is-for-so.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1506" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1506"><a href="http://this-is-for-so.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1507" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1507"><a href="http://this-is-for-so.com/my-account/">My Account</a></li>
</ul></div></nav></div></div>           </div><!-- Main Header Container -->
        </div><!-- ast-row -->
            </div> <!-- Main Header Bar -->
</div> <!-- Main Header Bar Wrap -->

            
        </header>
```

What could be the problem? If it will not work using code, is there any free plugin available to do this?

Comment: Any screenshot or any codepen

Comment: How's your HTML look like?

Comment: Added, Any clue?

Comment: @AskMe Send me the site link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just applying the code to the wrong element. In your CSS, you use the ID of `#masthead` but in your html code, the element has the class of `.main-header-bar-wrap`. So this could be the reason for your issue. But I want to take it a bit further to make sure your problem gets solved.

---

First of all I would like to make some improvements to your CSS code. You should put together the properties that belong together, like `width` and `height`. This way to will have a better overview of the styles. Avoid using properties that are not needed or will have no effect.

```
.main-header-bar-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-bottom:0.5px solid #dadada;
}
```

In your image, the text is on the right. So you do not need the `text-align: center`. The `margin: 0 auto` is meant to center align elements. But your navigation is a 100% width, so you do not need to center the navigation bar. Moreover, the `top` and `left` is enough, as it tells the browser where to put the element, and the `width: 100%` will stretch the whole page.

---

1. Use the inspector in your browser (right click) to find out, if your code gets applied.

It may be a issue with the "custom styles" field of your theme and the code is not used at all. So you do not get the result that you are looking for.

2. Make sure your styles are not getting overwritten by the theme files

In some cases for weird reasons, custom styles are not used at the bottom of the CSS file, but at the top. So it can be the case, that your styles are getting overwritten down the code. You can make sure your styles are used with using `!important`. Using the inspector of your browser (step 1) will show you that the style is overwritten, by showing you that the styles are striked out. For example:

```
.main-header-bar-wrap {
    position:fixed !important;
    top:0 !important;
    left:0 !important;
    z-index: 100 !important;
}
```